# Update TextBoxes bound to properties backed by the same local variable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, reactiveui

In an App using ReactiveUI, I have two properties backed by the same local variable.  Then the properties are used to bind to two textboxes where one showing the value and the other showing the value times 2.  I need to have one box reflects the change in the other box.

ViewModel:

```
public class AppViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    private int? _boxCommon;
    public int? boxOrg
    {
        get => _boxCommon;
        set
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"**** Check1: {value}");
            _ = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _boxCommon, value);
        }
    }
    public int? boxDouble
    {
        get => _boxCommon * 2;
        set
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"**** Check2: {value}");
            _ = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _boxCommon, (int)value / 2);
        }
    }

    private int? lastVal;

    public AppViewModel()
    {
        _boxCommon = 10;
        lastVal = 10;
        
        // Reflect changes to the other box.
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.boxOrg)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
            .Select((t) =>
            {
                if (t != lastVal)
                {
                    return t * 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    return boxDouble;
                }
            })
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Subscribe((t) => boxDouble = t);  // seems reduntdant cause both backed by the same var.

        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.boxDouble)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(800))
            .Select((t) =>
            {
                if (t != lastVal)
                {

                    return t / 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    return boxOrg;
                }
            })
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Subscribe((t) => boxOrg = t);            
    }
}
```

View:

```
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow 
    x:Class="ReactiveDemo.MainWindow"
    x:TypeArguments="reactivedemo:AppViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:reactivedemo="clr-namespace:ReactiveDemo"
    xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
    Title="Test" Height="150" Width="200"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Margin="12">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="OrgNum: "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="orgBox" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="DoubleNum: "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="doubleBox" />
    </Grid>
</reactiveui:ReactiveWindow>
```

View code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ViewModel = new AppViewModel();

    this.WhenActivated(disposableRegistration =>
    {
        // Notice we don't have to provide a converter, on WPF a global converter is
        // registered which knows how to convert a boolean into visibility.
        this.Bind(ViewModel,
            viewModel => viewModel.boxOrg,
            view => view.orgBox.Text)
            .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);
        this.Bind(ViewModel,
            viewModel => viewModel.boxDouble,
            view => view.doubleBox.Text)
            .DisposeWith(disposableRegistration);

    });
}
```

When I make changes in one box, the Trace does print out the new value set to the other box.  However, the GUI element is not updated with the new value. New to WPF and ReactiveUI, any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually you would **use** **just** **one** **property** and bind it to both textboxes.
The one that shall display/edit the value multiplied by two would use a  `IValueConverter` that multiplies by two in `Convert`  and divides by two in `ConvertBack`.

Comment: Thanks.  So it is that simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would rather use ValueConverter than your solution:

ViewModel:

```
private int _boxSingle;
public int BoxSingle
{
    get => _boxSingle;
    set
    {
        this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _boxSingle, value);
    }
}
```

Bindings:

```
this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.BoxSingle, view => view.textBox1.Text)
    .DisposeWith(d);

this.Bind(ViewModel, vm => vm.BoxSingle, view => view.textBox2.Text, 
        v => (v * 2).ToString(), 
        v => int.Parse(v) / 2 )
    .DisposeWith(d);
```

Comment: In my application, the calculations are more complex and often involving rounding errors.  So a change in one box will update the other box, and then that new change will reflect back to the original box and since the numbers do not agree, this may go on for a few cycles.  Just wonder is there a way to force an update-and-stop.

Comment: I provided you a simplest solution for what you asked. Anyway, of course it's possible, you can for example write a dedicated Setter methods that will handle the rounding errors. I strongly recommend to not let do as you called it "cycles" between properties. At some point it ussualy makes a big problems.